# Define a scheme function for infix

Tags: scheme, infix-operator

How to define a scheme function for infix-calculator?

For example when I enter `(infix '(2 + 3))` it should evaluate 5

If I enter `(infix '(7 - 3)` it should evaluate 4

Comment: `(define-syntax (infix l) (syntax-case l (quote) ((_ '(a b c)) #'(b a c))))`

Comment: How about `(7 - 3 * 4)`? Do you only support 3 elements per expression? Do you allow sub expressions like `((7 + 2) - (4 +1))`? How do you think such an expression needs to be handled to support deeply nested expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get really complex quite fast. Consider `(1 - 2 * 3)`. 
If your calculator only supports addition and negation, this is still not trivial. Consider `(5 - 5 - 5)`. If you consider the input as left associative, you'll get the correct -5, but if you read it as right associative (which is a common mistake if you parse the expression with some LL parser), you'll get 0.

In order to transform from infix to prefix (which is how you'll calculate your result in Scheme) correctly, you'll usually want to parse the entire input into a parse tree, and once that's done correctly, the rest is, actually, trivial (the tree nodes are operations and the leaves are numbers).

If you only support expressions of two operands, this is easy, just use `cadr` to know which operator you got, and apply (maybe using `eval`<sup>[1]</sup>) that operation to the operands

---

<sub>[1] If you do use `eval`, note Alex Knauth's comment below.</sub>

Comment: I would avoid using `eval` if it's possible.

Comment: @AlexKnauth, why?

Comment: Because it's not as "well-defined" as other functions. In a Repl you could redefine `*` from multiplication to a [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)), [kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), or [pointer deference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator), or anything really. The `*` or `+` that you wrote in a quote with some _intended meaning_ in its static context, instead takes its meaning from outside itself, to be overridden somewhere else dynamically. The `quote` looses the local meaning, and the `eval` has meaning overridden non-locally.

Comment: Sure, yeah, eval implements dynamic binding, but I wouldn't call say it's less well-defined. That's its definition.
However, it's a good warning to add. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This only works for + and - but I find the syntax,

```
(define-syntax infix 
  (syntax-rules (+ -)
    ((_ a) a)
    ((_ a + b ...) (+ a (_ b ...)))
    ((_ a - b ...) (- a (_ b ...))))
```

One uses it as (infix 1 + 2 - 9 + 10)